# Trying to add prefixes to url if not present in pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add prefixes to urls in my 'Websites' Column. I can't figure out how to keep each new iteration of the helper column from overwriting everything from the previous column.

for example say I have the following urls in my column:

```
http://www.bakkersfinedrycleaning.com/
www.cbgi.org
barstoolsand.com
```

This would be the desired end state:

```
http://www.bakkersfinedrycleaning.com/
http://www.cbgi.org
http://www.barstoolsand.com
```

this is as close as I have been able to get:

```
def nan_to_zeros(df, col):
    new_col = f"nanreplace{col}"
    df[new_col] = df[col].fillna('~')
    return df

df1 = nan_to_zeros(df1, 'Website')
df1['url_helper'] = df1.loc[~df1['nanreplaceWebsite'].str.startswith('http')| ~df1['nanreplaceWebsite'].str.startswith('www'), 'url_helper'] = 'https://www.' 
df1['url_helper'] = df1.loc[df1['nanreplaceWebsite'].str.startswith('http'), 'url_helper'] = ""
df1['url_helper'] = df1.loc[df1['nanreplaceWebsite'].str.startswith('www'),'url_helper'] = 'www'


print(df1[['nanreplaceWebsite',"url_helper"]])
```

which just gives me a helper column of all `www` because the last iteration overwrites all fields.
Any direction appreciated.

Data:

```
{'Website': ['http://www.bakkersfinedrycleaning.com/', 
             'www.cbgi.org', 'barstoolsand.com']}
```

Comment: remove the `df1['url_helper'] = `  from the beginning of the three lines?

Comment: Thanks! That was driving me crazy!

Comment: if you fix the typo, "url_helper" column returns `['', 'www', 'https://www.']`. Is that correct? Shouldn't it be `['', 'http://', 'https://www.']`?

Comment: it seems to be returning correctly for me...

Comment: Aren't you trying to do `df['url_helper']+df['Website']` in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, there are 3 things to fix here:

1. `df1['url_helper'] =`  shouldn't be there
2. `|` should be `&` in the first condition because `'https://www.'` should be added to URLs that start with neither of the strings in the condition. The error will become apparent if we check the first condition after the other two conditions.
3. The last condition should add `"http://"` instead of `"www"`.

Alternatively, your problem could be solved using `np.select`. Pass in the multiple conditions in the conditions list and their corresponding choice list and assign values accordingly:

```
import numpy as np
s = df1['Website'].fillna('~')
df1['fixed Website'] = np.select([~(s.str.startswith('http') | ~s.str.contains('www')), 
                                  ~(s.str.startswith('http') | s.str.contains('www')) 
                                 ], 
                                 ['http://' + s, 'http://www.' + s], s)
```

Output:

```
                                  Website                            fixed Website
0  http://www.bakkersfinedrycleaning.com/   http://www.bakkersfinedrycleaning.com/
1                            www.cbgi.org                      http://www.cbgi.org
2                        barstoolsand.com              http://www.barstoolsand.com
```